# Random number generation in Tensorflow is very slow (tensorflow-gpu)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, random, gpu

I have been starting to learn Tensorflow (on GPU) and have been playing with some of the basic functions, including random number generation with Tensorflow Probability. I have found that the random number generation to be surprisingly slow. Here is the code I used to test:

```
import time
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
tfd = tfp.distributions

size = (100,100)
counts = np.random.randint(1000,size = size)
probs = 0.5*np.ones(size)

t_counts = tf.cast(tf.convert_to_tensor(counts),tf.float64)
t_probs = tf.convert_to_tensor(probs)

N = 20
samples = np.zeros((size[0],size[1],N))
tic = time.time()
for i in range(N):
    samples[:,:,i] = np.random.binomial(counts,probs)
print('Numpy took',time.time()-tic,'seconds')

t_samples = []
b = tfd.Binomial(t_counts,t_probs)
tic = time.time()
for i in range(N):
    t_samples.append(b.sample())
print('Tensorflow took',time.time()-tic,'seconds')
```

I expected a marginal speedup over numpy at these array sizes but instead found Tensorflow to be dramatically slower. For the given size the output I get is:

```
Numpy took 0.04088950157165527 seconds
Tensorflow took 404.8193895816803 seconds
```

which seems dramatic. I tried scaling up the size of the size of the array to see how it scaled, and for `size = (200,200)` I get:

```
Numpy took 0.16755127906799316 seconds
Tensorflow took 1649.4787373542786 seconds
```

So tensorflow (ostensibly using the GPU) seems to be scaling in exactly the same way as numpy using the CPU. Is this expected behavior? I haven't been able to find any benchmarks for Tensorflow random number generation but it's not something I have specialized expertise in. Is there something that I am doing wrong when setting this up?